# Can a BSOD be reliably detected after rebooting into another OS?

Tags: windows, bsod

I need to detect a reboot caused by BSOD in a different OS. Can such a situation be traced? Is a memory dump enough for it? Windows 7 displays a nice dialog that a system has recovered from a serious error - how does it know?

Comment: Why don't you give more information. What caused the BSOD? Did you look at the windows 7 minidump? Which OS was it? What exact steps did you take to produce these results? ...

Comment: BSODs are caused by drivers and I'd love to be more specific but I'm not really allowed to.

Answer (score 2):

Windows provides an interface to register a [callback on bugchecks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540674%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) So you might register a function which does something specific to a bug check - creating a simple file or something like that, then in this other operating system you might check whether this file exists - if it does then your bugcheck callback was executed ergo. a bug check has occurred? Of course what you need to take into consideration is that the call to your function is issued at IRQL of HIGH_LEVEL so you have to see what restrictions apply and also this is in the domain of windows driver development.

Comment: The question says "__after__ rebooting into __another__ OS". That OS might not be Windows at all, and placing a callback after the BSOD is, well, futile.

Comment: what if in this callback he can create a file or something which persists. So that the other OS can check if this "thing" exists? Though I can't seem to find an adequate reason to want to do this

Comment: I've looked into BugCheckCallback, but I haven't got any idea if it is allowed to write to disk - IOW, I don't understand what the limitations written at http://www.osronline.com/ddkx/kmarch/other_1anb.htm mean. I'd be satisfied with being able to write to a predefined sector on the disk, though a file would obviously be better.

Comment: I think it will be better if you post on the NTDEV mailing list at osronline.com but state the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Thanks for the link. The issue revolves around testing drivers, unfortunately I can't say much more.

Comment: It won't be possible to write into file during bugcheck due to IRQL=HIGH_LEVEL. Actually, there is not much that can be done at this level. You can, of course, store the required information inside the memory dump file but that would require you to be able to analyze the memory dump from the second OS you're talking about.

Answer (score 1):

Searching the internet it seems Windows *tries* to generate dump files in `C:/Windows/Minidump`. You can look for files there. Note that I say *tries*, because a BSOD may be so fatal that a dump file could not be created (for example during a hard drive crash, for obvious reasons).

You can look for creation dates on the files to detect the most recent one.

This obviously requires that you can mount the Windows filesystem in the other OS, but it seems a decent solution.

Comment: Interestingly, it *tries* to generate the dump even if the BSOD is caused by the hard drive vanishing (my mobo/SATA controllers and early-gen SATA3 SSD get into arguments regularly, causing the mobo to dump the drive, a BSOD, and requiring a cold reboot). Windows sees the crash on the next boot, though I've never looked for the dump.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a simple Windows service that writes status information somewhere that the other OS can look for it.  This could be, for example, one of the unused sectors after the MBR, a dedicated partition, or a USB memory stick.

When the service starts you write a message to indicate that Windows is up and running, perhaps with a timestamp.  You might update this every so often, you could even include status information such as CPU load or driver load/unload events if that would be useful.  When the service detects that the system is shutting down, it writes a message saying so.  When your other OS looks at this information, if the last message didn't say the system was intentionally shutting down, then you can conclude that Windows crashed.  Windows does something similar so that the boot loader can offer to boot the system in safe mode.

Obviously, this doesn't allow you to distinguish between a BSOD and other types of crashes, and you'd get a false positive if the system lost power.  You also wouldn't be able to detect a BSOD if it occurred during the system shutdown process.  Whether these caveats matter depend on the details you're not telling us.

Answer (score 0):

By default Windows will log an event to the Event log when a system crashes. (See my comment below).

Comment: I believe this happens after the system has rebooted to Windows, i.e., too late to be of use in this scenario.  Even if the event has already been written, it doesn't help unless you know a way to parse Windows event logs from another OS.

Comment: Hummm, the easiest way to write logs in kernelmode is through the kernel API of EventLog. But you might be right, I'm not sure if kernel writes the event after the reboot. Parsing Windows Event offline is possible, parsing binary data [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb309026%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or XML in Win7.

Answer (score 0):

Not in the normal way, as the crashdump is actually written to the pagefile by the code that does the BSoD, then *after reboot*, Windows writes this to the final dump file.